# How to control the delay perference of GStreamer OpenMAX H.264 encoder module?

Tags: pi-3, streaming-video, gstreamer

I am trying to build up a streamed network video using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and a USB camera. After reading [this tutorial](http://www.z25.org/static/_rd_/videostreaming_intro_plab/), I made a working pipeline, but the software H.264 encoder is very CPU intensive. (About 250% occupation for 320x240 resolution).

The `OpenMAX gstreamer` module provides hardware-accelerated H.264 encoding. I replaced `x264enc` with `omxh264enc`, the pipeline still works, but the latency becomes about 10 seconds, as `omxh264enc` doesn't have the `tune=zerolatency` option that is provided by `x264enc`.

So here comes the questions:

- How can I adjust the latency preference in the `OpenMAX gstreamer` plugin?
- Or I do have to throw away `gstreamer` but use `OpenMax IL` directly?
- An additional question: could the hardware H.264 encoder process multiple (low resolution) video streams simultaneously, or it can only handle one at a time?